# Xamarin Forms (Android) How to do the Touch Test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, skiasharp

[Example](https://edge.alluremedia.com.au/m/g/2014/08/Samsung1.jpg)

I would like to do a touch test with Xamarin forms, I made a touch screen with skiasharp, but it's just drawing.

I want to complete the test when the frames on screen are full.

Comment: Hi, by `touch test`, what do you mean?

Comment: I want to paint the screen with finger,

Comment: the test finishes after the entire screen is painted.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late, have you solved your problem? By `paint the screen with finger`, click or swipe?  If you want to click everywhere on your phone, I suggest you use Monkey to do the test.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) is about the monkey, you can use adb command to test it.